# Qt platform DLL qwindows.dll not copied to platform directory on build in Visual Studio with CMake and vcpkg

Tags: qt, cmake, vcpkg

I have distilled this very simple CMake project that uses vcpkg and builds a dead simple Qt gui application just showing a main window. I can get it to build successfully in Visual Studio 2022 but I cannot get it to run seamlessly. The problem arises because the Qt platform DLL isn't copied to the output location with the other DLL dependencies in the post build step.

The `qwindows.dll` (or `qwindowsd.dll`) file is meant to be copied to the output location with the executable and other DLLs but in a `platforms\` subdirectory. This does not happen during a build, but if I create the directory and copy it manually then the application works.

To me this is something that should work seamlessly as part of the build process so I'm curious to know if I'm doing something wrong or I've set something up incorrectly.

Now I know that the simplest hacky solution would be to manually put a CMake post build step to copy the appropriate DLL from the `vcpkg_installed` directory to the output directory. But this seems like a hack as the system should handle this already otherwise many other people would be having this issue as well.

**So the questions I'm asking:**

- Am I missing something trivial here in the configuration?
- Am I not understanding something with how CMake + Qt work?
- Is this combination of CMake, vcpkg, and Qt a supported configuration that is expected to work?

---

The `CMakeLists.txt` is (and mostly taken from Qt's own example):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22 FATAL_ERROR)

project(QtTest LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)
qt_standard_project_setup()

add_executable(QtGuiTest
    Source/Main.cpp
    Source/MainWindow.cpp
    Source/MainWindow.hpp
)

target_link_libraries(QtGuiTest PRIVATE Qt6::Core Qt6::Gui Qt6::Widgets)
set_target_properties(QtGuiTest PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE ON MACOSX_BUNDLE ON)
```

The `CMakePresets.json` is:

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
        "major": 3,
        "minor": 22,
        "patch": 0
    },
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "default",
            "displayName": "Default",
            "generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022",
            "architecture": "x64",
            "toolchainFile": "$env{VCPKG_ROOT}\\scripts\\buildsystems\\vcpkg.cmake"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `vcpkg.json` is:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg/master/scripts/vcpkg.schema.json",
    "name": "qtguitest",
    "version": "0.1",
    "dependencies": [
        "qtbase"
    ]
}
```

Then I execute CMake to build out of the source tree with the `default` preset.

---

The code for the application is literally this:

```
// MainWindow.hpp
#pragma once
#include <QtGui>

class MainWindow : public QWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWindow* parent = nullptr);
};

// MainWindow.cpp
#include "MainWindow.hpp"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWindow* parent)
    : QWindow(parent)
{}

// Main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include "MainWindow.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication q_application{argc, argv};
    MainWindow main_window;
    main_window.show();
    return q_application.exec();
}
```

---

For reference I'm using:

- The latest Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition (as of 1/10/2022)
- CMake 3.22 installed (though vcpkg downloads 3.24 and uses that)
- vcpkg (as of 1/10/2022)
- Qt 6.3.2 is being installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to help from the other answers here I was able to figure this snippet out to add to the CMake configuration I had above.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET QtGuiTest POST_BUILD 
    COMMAND Qt6::windeployqt
    ARGS $<TARGET_FILE:QtGuiTest>
)
```

Which ends up calling the `windeployqt` application in the simplest manner in a post-build step.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware you have to call a tool called windeployqt to scan your source/binaries and build a list of stuff needed. Than it should automatically deploy that. Be aware that it might be not enough as some libs/plugins might have external dependencies and those might not be taken into consideration. Some dynamic dependencies or plugins might not be recognized as well, but look into windeployqt help to understand what you can achieve.

Comment: I thought that's what the vcpkg cmake scripts would have been doing but I couldn't trace through the logs well enough to verify that. I did run the `windeployqt` executable and while it did create the appropriate subdirectories and copy the platform `qwindows.dll` into that location it did not copy other necessary DLLs. So by itself it's not a good solution.

Comment: You are technically correct that windeployqt needs to be run but I haven't been able to find the right CMake incantations to make it run correctly for debug and release from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic in vcpkg to automatically deploy Qt6 dlls to where they are needed. Readup on https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html to learn what is necessary.

Also for Qt 6.3 read up on https://www.qt.io/blog/cmake-deployment-api . Qt has its own cmake API to help in deployment.

If you want to manually call windeployqt from cmake make sure you use the cmake target! In vcpkg the target has been adjusted to take care of release/debug.

An alternative to deploy the dlls is to deploy a qt.conf with the correct paths set. There is a debug/release variant in `<vcpkg_installed>/<triplet>/tools/Qt6` which could be used as a template to correctly set it up

Comment: For a simple convenient development solution would you recommend creating/copying a `qt.conf` or integrating calling `windeployqt` (or the relevant batch file for debug)?
Also what do you mean by using the cmake target? Did you have a specific cmake based qt target in mind?

Comment: Qt6 has an imported target in `share/Qt6CoreTools/Qt6CoreToolsTargets(-debug|-release).cmake` for windeployqt. You can directly use imported binary targets in execute_process.   It is probably better calling windeployqt or using the new deployment api.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the last sentence, do you mean that using the imported binary targets is better than manually calling windeployqt and better than using the deployment api? Or the other way around that it is better to call windeployqt manually or use the deployment API (building a script and running it etc).

Comment: I would say use the deployment api since that is what upstreams wants people to use in the future. If you however want to call windeployqt manually use the imported target (probably Qt6::windeployqt but i didn't check the naming) to invoke windeployqt.

Comment: Thanks! I added a post build command that calls the windeployqt target and that seems like the simplest thing to enable simple build & run from Visual Studio. The deployment API seems like a bit of overkill for just building and running from VS, but I'll look into it for creating installers etc.